# How to install H.239? From the H323plus or openh323gk or where?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora, centos, voip

I have downloaded this, but i dont see in the ./configure output anything related to h.239. Any idea? downloaded ex: http://waix.dl.sourceforge.net/project/openh323gk/Sources/2.3.3/

```
config.status: creating plugin-config.h

=================== Plugin configuration ======================
 prefix                           : /usr/local
 exec_prefix                      : ${prefix}
 libdir                           : ${exec_prefix}/lib
 Audio Codec plugin install dir   : ${libdir}/opal-1.22.0/codecs/audio
 Video Codec plugin install prefix: ${libdir}/opal-1.22.0/codecs/video
 LID plugin install prefix        : ${libdir}/opal-1.22.0/lid
 FAX plugin install prefix        : ${libdir}/opal-1.22.0/fax

                              GSM :  yes (internal)
                          gsm-amr :  yes
                             iLBC :  yes (internal)
                            Speex :  yes (internal, version 1.1.11.1)
                            LPC10 :  yes
                            G.726 :  yes
                        IMA_ADPCM :  yes
                              SBC :  no

                           H.261  :  yes
                           H.263  :  no (ffmpeg version)
                     H.263/H.263+ :  no
                           H.264  :  no
                          THEORA  :  no
                    MPEG4 Part 2  :  no
                            CELT  :  no

                     SpanDSP FAX  :  no

                            CAPI  :  no
           Quicknet xJACK support :  no
         Voicetronics VPB support :  yes

                         OS Type  :  linux-gnu
                    Machine Type  :  i686

 If all settings are OK, type make and make install 
========================================================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me whether H323plus supports h.239, but [GnuGK](http://www.gnugk.org/) claims to have support, and [precompiled binaries](http://www.gnugk.org/h323download.html) (as well as source code) are available for several operating systems.